# Can we use bit field for an array which is member of the structure in c?

Tags: c, arrays, bit

Can we use bit field of an array which is a part of the structure? Is this possible in C?

```
typedef struct convert
{
    unsigned char data[7] : 5;                                        //5x7
};
```

Comment: Why would you want this?

Comment: I think if you want a vector of booleans (1bit) this could be useful (if it ever worked) in some corner cases.. some very rare corner cases...

Comment: std::vector<bool> (with caveats) or dynamic_bitset

Comment: If you are going for optimizations here just be adviced that the small saving in memory has a greater impact on performance. Try to look at the assembly output of bitfield manipulation to see the result.

Comment: And why the downvotes? I would think that in general we are trying to discuss the quality of the question, not the code. To me this seems a perfectly valid c question about horrible hard to maintain code.

Answer (score 4):

No you can not do that.

- Bitfields can only be of type `int`
- Bitfields are padded to the size of the next element in the `struct`.

If your array is small enough then you may assign them individual names and make 7 5-bit bitfields, but that is probably not what you want.

Shifting them manually with a macro will be your best bet and as fast.